# How do I get an item but only if is a sibiling of a certain tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a long html but here's a fragment:

```html
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text:name, css: isActive() ? 'variable-active': 'variable-inactive'" class="variable-active">Vehicle</td>
    <td data-bind="text:value">Ford</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td data-bind="text:name, css: isActive() ? 'variable-active': 'variable-inactive'" class="variable-inactive">Model</td>
    <td data-bind="text:value">Focus</td>
</tr>
```

I want to get all the content tags based on if it is "variable-active", and then get the value from the next 'td' tag. In this case, as the second class tag is "variable-inactive", the output should be:

```
"Vehicle - Ford"
```

I managed to get the first tags based on the "variable-active" but I can't get the second values from the other tags. This is my code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open ("html.html","r") as f:

doc = BeautifulSoup(f,"html.parser")

tag = doc.findAll("tr")[0]

print(tag.findAll(class_="variable-active")[0].contents[0]) #vehicle

tag.findNextSibling(class_="variable-active") # nothing
```

Comment: `.variable-active + td { }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to structure your search a little bit different:

```py
tag = soup.findAll("tr")[0]

tag1 = tag.find(class_="variable-active")  # <-- use .find
tag2 = tag1.findNextSibling()              # <-- use tag1.findNextSibling() to find next sibling tag

print(tag1.text)                           # <-- use .text to get all text from tag
print(tag2.text)
```

Prints:

```
Vehicle
Ford
```

---

Another version using CSS selectors:

```py
data = soup.select(".variable-active, .variable-active + *")
print(" - ".join(d.text for d in data))
```

Prints:

```
Vehicle - Ford
```